# Setting All Drafts to 'exclude-from-catalog' in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

Is there anyway to do this programatically? Meaning via a PHP script on my localhost, exporting and then importing back in-- or any other way that would work.

Here's what I'm talking about:

The table `wp_terms` is where I found the `exclude-from-catalog` `term_id`

[image]

I've tested one product page out on the backend, and then did this query in MySQL/PHPMyAdmin

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON ( pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key='_visibility' )
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id)
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
and t.term_id = 7;
```

And I can see the product I set this to with a whole bunch of columns.

[image]

The `post_id` / `object_id` both reference the product page ID I manually set to exclude from catalog.

My issue is, if I do a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON ( pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key='_visibility' )
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id)
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
and post_status = 'draft';
```

It's returning all the post meta for every instance on every page... that query almost returns 400,000 results.

Seeing how `wp_terms` obviously has a close relationship with `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` I'm thinking this is not going to be a simple task.

Furthermore it seems only a new `meta_id` along with the `taxonomy` `product_visibility` is created only when you specify something in the backend (such as `featured`, `outofstock`, or `exclude-from-catalog`).

Is this an impossible task? Is the WordPress/WooCommerce terms structured so I'm not able to do this and have to manually set a `product_visibility` for each of my drafted products in wp-admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

You could do something along the lines of:
`wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'exclude-from-catalog', 'product_visibility' );`

Getting all posts by status, use [Wp_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). I added the `'fields' => 'ids'` param to limit the query to only ids, rather than gathering whole post objects.

On an array of posts that have *Draft or Pending* as a status or are an *auto-draft*

```
 function catalog_exclude_drafts() {
 $args = array(
               'post_type'   => 'product',
               'post_status' => array( 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft' ),
               'posts_per_page' => -1, 
               'fields'      => 'ids'
               );
            $drafts = new WP_Query( $args );
            $ids    = $drafts->posts;

            $map    = array_map( 'wrapper_for_set_obj', $ids );
 }

function wrapper_for_set_obj( $post_id ) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'exclude-from-catalog', 'product_visibility' );     
}
```

You could [hook the above](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hook_to_WordPress) (or some perfected variant) on `init` to run once on localhost or something. To future proof your Drafts,  hook it on [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). In fact, you can hook it on `save_post_products` since WP 3.7 introduced `save_post{post_type}`.

One time update:
`add_action( 'init', 'catalog_exclude_drafts' );`

Going forward:
`add_action( 'save_post_products', 'wrapper_for_set_obj' );`

Comment: Note: there may be other post_stati to consider, but if only _drafts_, you can just set `'post_status' => 'draft'`

Comment: Ah, thank you :) Brilliant response. I should've known WordPress already had their own clever way of doing these things.

Comment: But I'm having issues with it... does not seem to be working.  It definitely fired on `init`.  I also tried it by saving a draft with keeping the second function active.  All the drafts still say `Catalog visibility: Shop and search results` instead of `Search Results Only`. Additionally that MySQL `t.term_id = 7` is outputting the same single result. Not really sure what the issue is.  I'll take a closer look at it tomorrow definitely.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks again. Just needs a couple minor edits. `'post_type'   => 'product',` instead of products.  I also had to add to the array `'posts_per_page' => -1` because it wasn't retrieving all the posts.  Now all drafts are `Search Results Only`... so glad I didn't have to do this one-by-one, there are thousands :)

Comment: hey! awesome. yeah, i should have figured the `'posts_per_page' => -1`, I'll update the answer for anybody else running across it with that and correct `post_type`. Side note: The [developer reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) is really helpful for finding functions, classes, and various hooks as you need them.